# Plotting low-pressure centers over time using xarray and CORDEX data

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I want to plot low-pressure centers over time as a way of 'tracking' extreme storms across NW Europe. I can do this by plotting the contours of low pressure like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray

ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('D:\Data\CORDEX\Historical\*.nc')
ds
```

[image: Printout of ds]

```
plot = ds.psl[0].plot()
plot = ds.psl.isel(time=0).plot.contour('lon','lat', 
                                         levels=12, cmap = 'RdBu_r',vmax = 99000, ax=ax);
```

This shows me contours for low pressure values like so:

[image]

This is fine but it doesn't really do what I want. Ideally I would like just one point at the center of the low pressure depression to be plotted on the map, and then be able to follow this low pressure over each timestep, producing a line or a series of dots to show the progression of the low-pressure center over time.

As I want to do this for 3-hourly data over 150 years, I am thinking there must be an easier way of doing this using xarray than I can think of.

I'd eventually like to plot pseudo 'storm tracks' depending on the severity of the low pressure and the surrounding wind speeds (from the same model run), so maybe the contour function is the wrong one to be using? I am not sure.

I'm only interested in NW Europe but I can set the extent of the plot later to only include this area.

I'd really appreciate any help. In the end I would like a simple map of NW Europe with showing storm tracks and their severity for historial and future periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [Open Source storm tracking software](https://github.com/ecjoliver/stormTracking) or you have to build your own solution.

If you are interested to develope your own solution I recommend to use an algorthim to find local minima (and maxima)

E.g. scipy and numpy providing a good first attempt:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

minimums = signal.argrelextrema(ds.psl.values, np.less)
```

Antoher idea is to derive the gradient first . You can use `xarray.DataArray.differentiate` for this purpose. Gradient should be zero in the center of a high or low pressure system.

Comment: Ah - I didn't not realize there was already software out there - thanks very much for this link and your advice.

Comment: @Pad If this post helped you to find a solution please rate my answer as useful. Have a great day and fun with meteo data ;)